# Hiding application icon from MacOS dock when running the application from python code

Tags: python, macos, popen

I have a python code that uses POpen to run another application. This application is executed once on each file, and I have many files - so the icon of that application continuously bounces on the dock.
Is there a way to avoid the popping icon on mac dock when calling POpen?